Returning the last input entry



ID
Weight (kg)
BMI
Body-fat percentage
organ fat




248
54.1
20.5
19.7
7


248
54.3
20.2
19.5
6


248
54.2
20.4
19.6
6



I have this google sheet formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I3:I), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I3:I, SORT(FILTER({B3:B, D3:D, E3:E, F3:F, G3:G}, LEN(B3:B)), 1, FALSE), {2, 3, 4, 5}, FALSE), ""), ""))
My formula returns this set of value:



ID
Weight (kg)
BMI
Body-fat percentage
organ fat




248
54.1
20.5
19.7
7



but this section:
SORT(FILTER({B3:B, D3:D, E3:E, F3:F, G3:G}, LEN(B3:B)), 1, TRUE)
didn't help to sort the order because IDs are the same. ChangingTRUE/FALSE won't make a difference.
Is it possible to get this set of value



ID
Weight (kg)
BMI
Body-fat percentage
organ fat




248
54.2
20.4
19.6
6



by changing my formula?
Here's my currently formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I3:I), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I3:I, SORT(FILTER({B3:B, D3:D, E3:E, F3:F, G3:G}, LEN(B3:B)), 1, FALSE), {2, 3, 4, 5}, FALSE), ""), ""))
I tried changing to TRUE, but it didn't make any differences because IDs are the same:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I3:I), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I3:I, SORT(FILTER({B3:B, D3:D, E3:E, F3:F, G3:G}, LEN(B3:B)), 1, TRUE), {2, 3, 4, 5}, FALSE), ""), ""))
then I tried MAX, but it only returns the value with the largest ID number:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I3:I), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I3:I, FILTER({B3:B, D3:D, E3:E, F3:F, G3:G}, ROW(B3:B) = MAX(FILTER(ROW(B3:B), B3:B = I3:I))), {2, 3, 4, 5}, FALSE), ""), ""))

To return last entry you may use XLOOKUP(,,,,,-1). Search mode -1 means search from last to first. Or FILTER() then CHOOSEROWS(...,-1).

Use descriptive titles as written in [ask]

You may try FILTER() and CHOOSEROWS() function.
=MAP(TOCOL(I3:I,1),LAMBDA(x,CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(D:G,B:B=x),-1)))

Using XLOOKUP() try-
=MAP(TOCOL(I3:I,1),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,B:B,D:G,"",,-1)))



Thank you so much! I really appreciate you take time to make visual representation. That helps a lot
